# UI Hangs When While Loop is Placed Inside Runnable

Tags: android

I'm writing an app that will display the current download speed which will be updated every second. My Runnable class is able to update the UI with the value, but when I try to place it inside a loop so that it will continuously run and update the UI TextView every second, the app now hangs.

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SpeedMeter.TaskRunnableSpeedMeterMethods{

    private Thread mSpeedMeterThread;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private TextView downloadSpeedOutput;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        downloadSpeedOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);

        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
                SpeedMeter speedMeter = (SpeedMeter) inputMessage.obj;
                downloadSpeedOutput.setText(Long.toString(speedMeter.getmDownloadSpeedKB()));
            }
        };

        SpeedMeter speedMeter = new SpeedMeter(this);
        speedMeter.run();

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void setSpeedMeterThread(Thread currentThread) {
        mSpeedMeterThread = currentThread;
    }

    @Override
    public void setInternetSpeed(SpeedMeter speedMeter) {
        Message completeMessage = mHandler.obtainMessage(1, speedMeter);
        completeMessage.sendToTarget();
    }
}
```

And here's the other SpeedMeter.java:

```
public class SpeedMeter implements Runnable {

    final TaskRunnableSpeedMeterMethods mMainActivity;
    private long mDownloadSpeedKB;

    public SpeedMeter(TaskRunnableSpeedMeterMethods mainActivity) {
        mMainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        mMainActivity.setSpeedMeterThread(Thread.currentThread());
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

//        while(true) {

            long rxBytesPrevious = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            long rxBytesCurrent = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();

            long downloadSpeed = rxBytesCurrent - rxBytesPrevious;

            setmDownloadSpeedKB(downloadSpeed/1000);

            mMainActivity.setInternetSpeed(this);

//        }

    }

    public long getmDownloadSpeedKB() {
        return mDownloadSpeedKB;
    }

    public void setmDownloadSpeedKB(long mDownloadSpeedKB) {
        this.mDownloadSpeedKB = mDownloadSpeedKB;
    }

    interface TaskRunnableSpeedMeterMethods {
        void setSpeedMeterThread(Thread currentThread);
        void setInternetSpeed(SpeedMeter speedMeter);
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you need to implement service if want this type of operation

Comment: Do NOT use a service this this. A service is for long running operations that are not always user facing, which is overkill for what you're trying to do. Especially for something related to UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didnt start your runnable as a new thread instead you called the run function like a normal function (so u do the while loop on ur UI thread which blocks it)

replace

```
speedMeter.run();<br />
SpeedMeter speedMeter = new SpeedMeter(this);
```

with

```
new Thread(new SpeedMeter(this)).start();
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html for more infos on how to start a Runnable :)

Comment: @BAAZINGA that is not the proper solution, in memory crunch situation OS will kill this thread, for such type of activity where you are putting while(true) you need to implement service

Comment: @dex maybe im still new to android and i have no idea when android system kills what but he wanted to know why his code wont work and im pretty sure that my answer solves that if u have a better solution or tipp etc post ur own solution or edit mine so itll get better :)

Comment: Thanks! This directly resolved my issue. I'll learn how to implement this as a service as @dex recommended; it seems to be the better way of implementing this.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal way to do this would be to create an `AsyncTask` that would post a message to your UI thread, after it complete the task in the `doInBackground()` call.

### Standards

also the interface structure you are following does not make sense and does not follow good standards. Usually an interface is used as a callback, which is basically what you are doing. But the standard is to say onSomethingChangedA() or onSomethingChangedB() from OnSomethingChangedListener interface.

Comment: My comment got published before it was completed. :) I have a couple of questions:

1) dex suggested I implement it as a service instead; is it the same as creating an AsyncTask with a while(true) loop instead? 

2) Can you please share a link to the coding standards? I tried looking for an official one in the net, but found none. I got the naming styles following the Thread training in the [Android developers site](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

Comment: A service is for long running operations that are not always user facing, which is overkill for what you're tyrying to do. Especially for something related to UI. (1) with AsyncTask you need only start the async task and call doInBackground. yes, you could do while true and keep posting messages. Another way to be to start a thread and have that thread use a handler to communicate with the Mainthread. (2) there is no clear documentation about this but you can learn about how interfaces are used by looking at how View.OnClickListener() is designed. If I find one, i'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop is always true so app hangs its better to create a boolean and use `while(mboolean)` and put this in your loop

```
if(something){
 mboolean=false;
}
```

you can also use CountDownTimer.
for example:

```
new CountDownTimer(miliseconds,1000) 
//if you have download speed and download size you can find miliseconds
@Override
public void onTick(long l) {
//something you want to do every seconds
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {
//something you want to do on finish
}
```